# massif and top memory usage differences

Tags: c++, memory-management, top-command, massif

I am tracing how much memory an object is using. I have simple program which simply instantiate the object and the delete it.

If I look at the output of massif or if I look at the virtual memory from top I get completely different result. Do you have any ideas? When I use top I've simply added a `cin >> a` just to pause the program.

Answer (score 0):

massif measures how much heap you're using, but top command shows whole memory allocation for the computer, not for only you program's heap

Comment: I see, how to solve it? I've seen `--pages-as-heap` but it is not available on the version I have

Comment: @RuggeroTurra I dont understand what you're trying to solve, what is the problem?

Comment: I want to see the total amount of memory used by my program

Comment: total memory used by program is program size + heap size + stacks size

Comment: hm, use masiff... it shows all numbers, maybe except program size - just look via `ls` command to check size of binary